# Destroy Image over multiple slides

Tags: powerpoint

I'm trying to make a 'game-show' using PowerPoint.
I have 3 images (link lifelines) that appear on every slide, and I would like to be able to 'Fade' these out when clicked but then also destroyed on the upcoming slides as they are no longer usable.

Is this possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But if you're looking for someone to write the code for you, that's not the way StackOverflow works. But if YOU write the code and run into problems, post the code and a description of the problem here.  That IS how StackOverflow works.

Comment: okay, thanks for the advice